# How to set HTML element ID at client side

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms, client-side

We are trying to write a form at ASP.net using visual studio.
We want to be able to control the final client side ID of elements so we can refer to them in the jquery code easily.

The regular 'id' attribute at ASP.net gets an odd prefix that we cannot control at the client side.

How can we fully control the final client side ID of an element?

Thank you!

IE:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TBICDCode6"  runat="server" Width="240">
```

I want to be able to refer to the text box using

```
$("#TBICDCode6");
```

Comment: you can do the inverse instead - emit the actual ID somewhere on the server side (eg. in javascript), and look it up on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0, you can do this by setting [`Control.ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to `static`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TBICDCode6"  runat="server" 
        ClientIDMode="Static"
        Width="240">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Or, if you are using an older version of ASP.NET, try this.

```
$("#" + '<%= TBICDCode6.ClientID %>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#<%= TBICDCode6.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid this because I want to dynamically refer to linked fields using JQuery function...

Answer (score 1):

it's a well known fact that asp.net does nasty things to ids. it's supposed to be better in asp.net 4.0, but I haven't tried it yet.
try reading 'Referencing Server Controls in Client Script' [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx).
Alternatively, you can bypass the whole thing completly by using another attribute (such as `name`).
your selectors will then be `$("[name=someId]")`, instead of `$("#someId")`